# What is the alternative for open in python 2.4.3

Tags: python, linux

When I use `open()` in python 2.4.3, i get the following error

> `File "/tmp/chgjdbcconfig.py", line 16
>       with open("text.new", "wt") as fout:
>               ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I checked the python version and this is my output

> `Python 2.4.3`

I was looking for advice on what could be the alternative. I am trying to edit lines in an XML file on a linux server and I have no control over the upgrades of the python version.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: what is the `t` flag ... ive never seen that .. ahh google tells me its `ascii only mode` but I though just opening it without the `b` flag was sufficient for ascii only mode

Comment: @JoranBeasley Beasley I followed as it was form the link [replace-string-within-file-contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128144/replace-string-within-file-contents). My aim was to keep it as simple as possible. I wanted to perform the change contents of a file routine and I was not aware of the `with` problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`open` isn't missing in 2.4. What's missing is the `with` statement [(added in Python 2.5 as PEP-0343)](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

To do the same code without `with`:

```
fout = open("text.new", "wt")
# code working with fout file
fout.close()
```

Note the `fout.close()` is implicit when using `with`, but you need to add it yourself without

---

`with` statements have the added benefit of closing the file *even if an exception is raised,* so a more precise analogue would actually be:

```
fout = open("text.new", "wt")
try:
    # code working with fout file
finally:
    fout.close()
```

Comment: Note that this isn't quite equivalent.  When you use `with` your file is gauranteed to be closed even in the case of an exception.

Comment: very true. i'll go ahead and edit to use `try..finally`

Answer (score 0):

it's not `open()` it is choking on.  It is the `with` syntax.  Context managers did not exist in Python 2.4.

you must explicitly close the file also.

Comment: Thanks! The above one was much more detailed!