# Python line.replace returns UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-unicode

I have a tex file that was generated from rst source using Sphinx, it is encoded as UTF-8 without BOM (according to Notepad++) and named `final_report.tex`, with following content:

```latex
% Generated by Sphinx.
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,english]{sphinxmanual}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Preface}
Krimson4 is a nice programming language.
Some umlauts äöüßÅö.
That is an “double quotation mark” problem.
Johnny’s apostrophe allows connecting multiple ports.
Components that include data that describe how they ellipsis …
Software interoperability – some dash – is not ok.
\end{document}
```

Now, before I compile the tex source to pdf, I want to replace some lines in the tex file to get nicer results. My script was inspired by [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128144/replace-string-within-file-contents).

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

newFil=os.path.join("build", "latex", "final_report.tex-new")
oldFil=os.path.join("build", "latex", "final_report.tex")

def freplace(old, new):
    with open(newFil, "wt", encoding="utf-8") as fout:
        with open(oldFil, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as fin:
            for line in fin:
                print(line)
                fout.write(line.replace(old, new))
    os.remove(oldFil)
    os.rename(newFil, oldFil)

freplace('\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,english]{sphinxmanual}', '\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt, english]{book}')
```

This works on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7 as well as Python 3.5,
but it fails on Windows with Python 3.4. 
The error message I get is:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 11: character maps to <undefined>
```

where `201c` stands for left double quotation mark. If I remove the problematic character, the script proceeds till it finds the next problematic character.

In the end, I need a solution that works on Linux and Windows with Python 2.7 and 3.x. I tried quite a lot of the solutions suggested here on SO, but could not yet find one that works for me...

Comment: Hi @matth what do you have in line 19?

Comment: My example does not have 19 lines, I assume the error message refers to line 19 of  the `cp850.py` file.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971033/backporting-python-3-openencoding-utf-8-to-python-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the correct encoding with the `encoding="the_encoding"`:

```
with open(oldFil, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as fin,  open(newFil, "wt", encoding="utf-8") as fout:
```

If you don't the preferred encoding will be used.

[open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

*In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: locale.getpreferredencoding(False) is called to get the current locale encoding*

Comment: @matth,  what double quote? If you still have encoding issues then you don't have utf-8 encoded data

Comment: @matth, you have specified the encoding as utf-8 for both annd the error happens on write?

Comment: @matth, so setting the encoding fixed the first error but now you have another?

Comment: Yes it fixed the first error, but not my real world use case, I am still getting the UnicodeEncodeError. So I updated the question to be closer to my real use case.

Comment: All other errors disappear when I delete the `print()` statement used for debugging. My `sys.stdout.encoding` is `cp850` which is not able to display the unicode character.

Comment: All other errors disappear when I delete the print() statement used for debugging. My sys.stdout.encoding is cp850 which is not able to display the unicode character. Any idea how to print to stdout (I do not need it now, but it would be nice to know for future debugging). Also, Python 2 is now complaining about the encoding.

Comment: For python 2 you would need to use the io lib, using io.open. when I get back on my comp this evening I will add a link to a nice answer that allows you to print from a cmd shell, although I would recommend using cygwin as your default shell on windows or use an side like pycharm.

Comment: `io.open` did the trick, thanks. Should I test for the python version before importing or is it acceptable to import no matter whether py2 or 3?

Comment: No need,  Python3's open is io.open so the code will work as is for both 2.7 and 3