# Batch convert Maya files

Tags: python, maya, nuke

I'm actually working on a script to convert a very basic Maya `.ma` scene to Nuke `.nk` project using Maya batch mode (mayapy.exe)

I have found how to select, search infos from camera but I don't know how to export them in a text file, as a text file with `.nk` extention works in Nuke.
For the moment I use this to export the camera as FBX :

```
outputFilename = os.path.splitext(current)[0]+'.fbx'
    print "Output file: ", outputFilename

cmds.file(outputFilename, exportSelected=True, typ="FBX export", force=True, options="v=0;", es=1)
```

But that cant work for text file or `.nk` file as Maya doesn't have this option in export settings.
Any idea how I can specify to write in a text file with the `.nk` extention ?

Thank you.

Comment: As much as I knwo there is no nuke .nk exporter for maya. So the only solution is to find a script which already does what you want or write your own. That means you need to open a text file and fill it with the appropriate data from maya.

Comment: yes that's exactly my question, how to create a text file ? i know how to create the content but not the file itself
there is no .nk file but as a nuke .nk file is just a text file with .nk extention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **batch conversion** use a syntax like this to accomplish `fbx` export:

```
import maya.mel as mel

mel.eval('FBXExport -f "/Users/swift/Desktop/fileName";')
```

You'll get `fileName.fbx` file on your Desktop.

...or simply write what you want into `.nk` file...

```
fileName = "/Users/swift/Desktop/fileName.nk"

# pass in 'r' for reading a file
# pass in 'r+' for reading and writing a file
# pass in 'w' for overwriting the file
# pass in 'a' for appending to the file

fileWrite = open(fileName,'w')

# write here a content of .nk file
fileWrite.write('Hello, NUKE! ...blah, blah, blah...') 
fileWrite.close()
```

You'll get `fileName.nk` file on your Desktop.

---

For **non-batch conversion** use the code like this:

```
from pymel.core import *

fileName = fileDialog2()
print fileName[0]
fileWrite = open(fileName[0],'w')

# write here a content of .nk file
fileWrite.write('Hello, NUKE') 
fileWrite.close()
print open(fileName[0],'r').read()
```

In opened dialog box just type `fileName` with `.nk` extension. And you'll get `.nk` ASCII file.

Comment: the base work well but as i use other command to determine finename, i cant use your line
`fileName = "/Users/swift/Desktop/fileName.nk"`
i use :
`fileWrite = open(filename+'.nk', 'w')`
and it result
`aname.ma.nk` any idea to remove the .ma from it ? (even a minus 3 caractere can do the job)

Comment: You need a replace command. Here are some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128144/replace-string-within-file-contents