# Customize PyGal WorldMap chart's tooltip

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pygal

I'm using [pygal](https://www.pygal.org/en/3.0.0/documentation/types/maps/pygal_maps_world.html) for generate a world map chart in Google Colab.

The problem I'm facing is with the tooltip. I want to show only in the tooltip the name of the country and the number of videos found.

The result so far I've managed to get is as follows:

*Worldmap chart current output:*

[image: Worldmap chart with tooltip]

You can see there that the tooltip is composed as follows:

> Country name

> Number of videos

> Country name: 1

Example:

> United States

> 73 videos

> Unites States: 1

---

*Using the sample shown in the screenshot and in the sample above*, what I want to get is

Example:

> United States

> 73 videos

OR:

Example:

> Unites States: 73 videos

Here is the [Google Colab notebook sample](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1et8IlPiUCAGilGEocy8HxdmvFtZlo643?usp=sharing) I've created, so anyone can reproduce this issue.

This is the Worldmap chart settings:

```
# Save chart as svg: 
worldmap_chart.render_to_file('worldmap_result.svg', 
                              show_legend=True, 
                              human_readable=True, 
                              fill=True, 
                              print_labels=True, 
                              no_data_text="No data available", 
                              legend_at_bottom=True, 
                              pretty_print=True,
                              x_title="Hover the cursor on the country's name bellow or the map above:",
                              print_values=True, 
                              force_uri_protocol='https')
```

I've readed the [documentation](https://www.pygal.org/en/3.0.0/documentation/types/maps/pygal_maps_world.html) and searched, but, I'm not been able to find the correct configuration (*if possible*) for generate the expected tooltip.

Does anyone knows what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing for a few more hours, I finally decided to follow these steps:

- Generate/render the world chart in a file - in this case, a .svg file.
- Read the generated file in the previous step, find and replace certain svg tags - those that contains the data I don't want in the final chart.
- Download the modified file.

The said svg tags are as follows:

Example:

```
<desc class="value">Russian Federation: 1</desc>
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62008698/12511801), I was able to replace the svg tags and leave them empty. With that change, I was able to generate the world map chart as I required.

This is the full, modified and working code:

```
import types
# Library import:
from pygal_maps_world.maps import World
from pygal.style import DefaultStyle

worldmap_chart = World()
worldmap_chart.title = 'Channels distribution per country'

#list - source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716774/12511801
# Excludes "N/A" values: 
countriesData = df_countries.loc[df_countries['Country (channel)'] != "N/A"].to_dict('split')["data"]

# Loop the "countriesData" and replace the name of the country 
# with is ISO code - lowercase - in order to render the world map: 
for x in countriesData: 
  countryName = x[0]
  countryName = [x["id"].lower() for x in all_countries if x["name"] == countryName][0]
  x[0] = countryName

# Strings to replace:
js_strings = []

# Generate world map chart: 
#worldmap_chart.add('Countries', dict(countriesData))
for data in countriesData: 
  countryFound = [x["name"] for x in all_countries if x["id"].lower() == data[0]]
  if (len(countryFound) > 0): 
    countryFound = countryFound[0]
    worldmap_chart.add(countryFound, [{"value": data[0], "label" : (str(data[1]) + " video" + ("s" if data[1] != 1 else ""))}])
    js_strings.append('<desc class="value">{0}: 1</desc>'.format(countryFound))

# Save chart as svg - comment this line for print the chart in this notebook: 
worldmap_chart.render_to_file('chart_final_4.svg', 
                              show_legend=True, 
                              human_readable=True, 
                              fill=True, 
                              print_labels=True, 
                              no_data_text="No data available", 
                              legend_at_bottom=True, 
                              pretty_print=True,
                              x_title="Hover the cursor on the country's name bellow or the map above:",
                              print_values=True)
print("Chart saved in local storage - see file (chart_final_4.svg).")

# Render the chart in the notebook:
HTML_worldChart = str(worldmap_chart.render(show_legend=True, human_readable=True, 
                                        fill=True, print_labels=True, 
                                        no_data_text="No data available", 
                                        legend_at_bottom=True, 
                                        print_values=True, style=DefaultStyle(value_font_family='googlefont:Raleway',
                                                                              value_font_size=30,
                                                                              value_colors=('white',))))


# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62008698/12511801
from pathlib import Path
file = Path("chart_final_4.svg")

# Replace specific, conflicting countries by name:
file.write_text(file.read_text().replace('<desc class="value">Korea, Republic of: 1</desc>', '<desc class="value"></desc>'))
file.write_text(file.read_text().replace('<desc class="value">Russian Federation: 1</desc>', '<desc class="value"></desc>'))
file.write_text(file.read_text().replace('<desc class="value">Viet Nam: 1</desc>', '<desc class="value"></desc>'))

## This is due those countries are arranged as follows: 
##--country (<desc class="value">Russia: 1</desc>) no detected
##--country (<desc class="value">Vietnam: 1</desc>) no detected
##--country (<desc class="value">South Korea: 1</desc>) no detected

# Loop the strings to replace: 
for country in js_strings:
  file.write_text(file.read_text().replace(country, '<desc class="value"></desc>'))

print("(chart_final_4.svg) has been modified.")
```

***Output***: *world map chart modified - I'm modified the screenshot for include two tooltips at the same time.*

[image: Final world map chart modified]

---

Side note: it *might* not be the best way, but, for a lack of time and knowledge, I've decided to leave it *as is*. I'm open to any, better suggestions.